# sql to return unique list of UserID's based on 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

(not discussing the table design, its a done deal!)

I know how to do this query using a WHERE NOT IN clause, **but I was wondering how it could be done using a join.**

Note: rows are not unique, so we have to do a DISTINCT so as to not get duplicates.

```
Users (userID)
OldUsers(UserID)
```

So using the WHERE NOT IN clause I can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.userID)
FROM Users u
WHERE u.userID NOT IN (SELECT o.userID FROM OldUsers o)
```

**Performance is a key here also.**

Comment: 300 questions, 33% accept rating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct u.userID from Users u
left join OldUsers o on o.userId = u.userID
where o.userId is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `EXCEPT` keyword to do it this way:

```
SELECT UserID FROM Users
EXCEPT
SELECT UserID FROM OldUsers
```

As for performance: you'll just have to run the three scripts (your own with `NOT IN`, kragan's approach with `LEFT JOIN` and this one with `EXCEPT`) in comparison and measure for yourself what the speed is, how much resources they use etc. --> look at the execution plans, check out the IO statistics - the usual stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a correlated subquery and `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.userID)
FROM Users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT o.userID 
     FROM OldUsers o 
     WHERE o.UserID = u.userID)
```

If this is actually faster depends on the size of the tables, so it's another version to try out as marc_s has suggested.